# How to read an Array of Element Names from XMLSchema XML File in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I wanted to get the list of schema elements from xml. For example

```
<xs:schema id="SPPOnlineXML" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
 <xs:element name="SPPOnlineXML" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="lev_settings" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="lev_settings">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LEVID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="ATTHEADID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="MINDATETYPE" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="MINMONTH" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

from the above schema i wanted to create an array of elements "LEVID","ATTHEAD","MINDATETYPE","MINMONTH"

Comment: Do you need just all `<xs:element ..` nodes from this xml?

Comment: I have problems to fully understand your question. For example in your example XML which names would fit into the *",...................."* part? The other names I see, but apart from those names I only see *SPPOnlineXML* and *lev\_settings* but those are *before* the *LEVID*  you list first. Please clarify and also please give context why you need to obtain those names, this context can clarify as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain all *`xs:element name-attribute values`* as an array I suggest you pick SimpleXML and make use of xpath. Once you've got the XML in a string (or a file) it is really straight forward if you know the xpath expressions:

```
# Obtain all element names incl. complexTypes:

//xs:element/@name

# Obtain all element names excl. complexTypes and those
#  which contain anything incl. comments, text etc.:

//xs:element[not(node())]/@name
```

And per PHP code exmaple that looks like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

echo "Obtain all element names incl. complexTypes:\n";

$elementNames = array_map('strval', $xml->xpath('//xs:element/@name'));
print_r($elementNames);

echo "\nObtain all element names excl. complexTypes and those
  which contain anything incl. comments, text etc.:\n";

$elementNames = array_map('strval', $xml->xpath('//xs:element[not(node())]/@name'));
print_r($elementNames);
```

[See the online Demo.](http://eval.in/16798)

Comment: Above schema i'm not giving as string it will come in xml file file along with data. Here data means table rows and schema is table header column details that xml i created in c#

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();

$xml->load('test.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$result = $xpath->query('//xs:sequence/xs:element');
$res_array = array();
foreach($result as $element_node) {
        $res_array[] = $element_node->getAttribute('name');
}
var_dump($res_array);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "LEVID"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "ATTHEADID"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "MINDATETYPE"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "MINMONTH"
}
```

Comment: You can make use of Xpath querying for the attribute nodes already. Not that your code won't work but it would simplify it to directly query the attribute nodes.

Comment: showing 'Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: Undefined namespace prefix' for '$result = $xpath->query('//xs:sequence/xs:element');' line

Comment: For this to work and to fix the undefined namespace error, you need to register the namespaces, such as `$xpath->registerNamespace('xml', 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace');`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get all the xs:element of an XSD file on a html table, full code:

```
<table>
                <?php
                    // Load from xsd file
                    $url = "myFile.xsd";
                    $xml = file_get_contents($url, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
                    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);


                    $elementNames = array_map('strval', $xml->xpath('//xs:element/@name'));
                    foreach ($elementNames as $value) {
                        echo "<tr><td>$value</td></tr>";
                    }

                    $elementNames = array_map('strval', $xml->xpath('//xs:element[not(node())]/@name'));
                    foreach ($elementNames as $value) {
                        echo "<tr><td>--->$value</td></tr>";
                    }
                ?>
</table>
```

If you are looking for xs:attribute, you just need to replace all over the code the "xs:element" by "xs:attribute"